# What is the need for "over" in the following sentences?

Tags: prepositions

> They sent **over** a gift, *or*
>     They sent a gift.

> Come **over** to our house, *or*
>     Come to our house.

Is it not possible to make the meaning clear without using *over* in the sentence?

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/131949/difference-between-come-here-and-come-over-here has an answer that may satisfy the OP of the current question.

Answer (score 1):

Including *over* makes the sentence **more informal** and is an indicator that there is not much effort or distance involved.

"Come over to our house" means the same as "Come to our house", but it's far more likely to be used if it's only going to take ten minutes for the journey.

"They sent over a gift" doesn't necessarily involve an assessment of distance, but is an indicator of the effort (or the perceived effort) in the sending. "They sent a gift" implies a greater appreciation of the gift or the effort than "They sent over a gift".

Comment: Great! Perfect answer!!

Comment: @user168878 If you think so, then you could upvote and accept it.

Comment: I did. Am doing now for other answers too.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, the sentence makes perfect sense without the over.

It's similar to saying 'I've just come **up** from London'. It makes perfect sense to say 'I've just come from London' as well.

Comment: Why the people unnecessarily make it more complex using "over"?!!

Comment: I don't think colloquialism is exactly the right word, but it's essentially a less formal way of inviting someone to your house.